# Android:What is difference between setFlags and addFlags for intent

Tags: android

What is difference between setFlags and addFlags for intent. Could any one explain it please.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: I always appreciate a link to the official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#addFlags(int) and/or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags(int,%20int)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

When you use `setFlags` you are replacing the old flags... when you use `addFlags` you are appending new flags. Remember, a flag is just a integer which is power of two... in binary, flags look like this: 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc... (which in this case are 1, 2, 4, 8). So, what `addFlags` does is appending the integer you pass using the `|` operator.

```
// example... 
// value of flags: 1
intent.setFlags(2|4); 
// now flags have this value: 110
intent.addFlags(8); 
// now flags have this value: 1110
```

Comment: How can it possible  `intent.setFlags(2|4);` will give 110 value

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi in binary the LSB (least significant bit) for human readable values is the most right one. that means that the 0 of the 110 represents the value 2^0 = 1 . The second value 1 represents 2^1 = 2. And the third value represents 2^2=4. So using the OR | operator on 4 (100) and 2(010) is 110

Comment: This should not be confused with Window.setFlags/addFlags which have a different behaviour to the Intent methods.

Comment: May I know the uses of these intent flags? or can you tag me to the appropriate question?

Comment: What are the flags that are set to an Intent by default? i.e. what exactly does gets reset when we use Intent().setFlags()?

Answer (score 10):

```
intent.setFlags(int num);
```

This set flag controls how to handle the Intent.setflag mainly depends on  type of component being executed by the Intent.It returns the same intent object for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.

```
intent.addFlags(int num);
```

This helps to add additional flags to a particular intent with the existing values.this also returns the same intent object for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.

Answer (score 8):

```
 public Intent addFlags(int flags) {
    mFlags |= flags;
    return this;
}
public Intent setFlags(int flags) {
    mFlags = flags;
    return this;
}
```

Just found this from the source code,for reference.