# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not work invoked by actionbarmenu?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags, android-lifecycle

I start with showing the workflow graph of my app
[image]

Firstly, when app is lunched the checker is created, this activity check if user is logged or not, if not it goes to log_1 activity and checker activity is finished. 
Then the user choose the method in log1 -> put login data in log2 -> the system checks if the values are correct and here is start activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when i'm going to menu1. And when I click back button I exit the app so it works like it should. 
code for intent with flag:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginStation.this, ChooseMenu.class);
             //clears all activities in stack, and we only have acitivity which we going to 
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             startActivity(intent);
```

In every screen of menu I got the action bar with button log out and when I click it, the log1 screen is created with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but now when I click the back button it goes back to menu screen instead of exit the app.

> My goal is to when the user go to menu1 or log1 screen the backstack
>   should be clear, but apparently I made some mistakes and I have no
>   idea where. If i go from log3 to menu back stack is cleared, when I
>   use this same method to go from menu to log1 screen it doesn't clear
>   backstack.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code for clearing the stack   [Difference between addFlags and setFlags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664189/androidwhat-is-difference-between-setflags-and-addflags-for-intent)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginStation.this, ChooseMenu.class);
//clears all activities in stack, and we only have acitivity which we going to 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

[More info about it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: it doesn't work, if user is already logged and he goes straight to manu1, cause the flag firstly need to be added. I try something with adding flag in checker