# how to avoid returning to previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities, but since the second activity is allowing me to return with the back button, which should not happen, how to avoid this situation

**Activity 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

is it necessary to put finish() ?.
And I have a second question, what is the difference between setFlags and addFlags, where to use each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Preventing going back to the previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631095/android-preventing-going-back-to-the-previous-activity)

Answer (score 1):

- Finish the first activity
- override onBackPressed of the second to not call super (preventing it from finishing by button) in this solution if you finish this activity programatically you will still back to the first one.

I think the dif in set and add is that set override the value and add just bitwise the current value, if its the case in your example you have only NO_ANIMATION set.

Answer (score 0):

First question answer:

- [Android: Preventing going back to the previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631095/android-preventing-going-back-to-the-previous-activity)

Second question answer:

- [Android:What is difference between setFlags and addFlags for intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664189/androidwhat-is-difference-between-setflags-and-addflags-for-intent)