# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-input-method

I have creating emoji keyboard in android but i can add share this app button in keyboard view.

here my on click share method.

```
public void shareapp() {
    String shareText = getResources().getString(R.string.share_text);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    Intent chooseIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share this via");
    getApplication().getApplicationContext().startActivity(chooseIntent);
}
```

but on click the share app button an error occur
see Error:

```
01-11 13:36:03.728 8795-8795/com.example.napturalistamoji E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.napturalistamoji, PID: 8795
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:747)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:734)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:345)
    at com.example.napturalistamoji.service.KeyboardService.shareapp(KeyboardService.java:685)
    at com.example.napturalistamoji.service.KeyboardService.onClick(KeyboardService.java:566)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

any one can help me to solve my problems?

Comment: You need to call `addFlags()` on the `chooseIntent` that you get back from `createChooser()`.

Comment: Marking this as duplicate isn't really helpful, as unfortunately the linked duplicate question doesn't have any clear answers to OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set flag to your intent when starting activity like this

```
Intent chooseIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share this via");
chooseIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().getApplicationContext().startActivity(chooseIntent);
```

You setting a flag on wrong intent.

Comment: Both methods setFlags() and addFlags() can be used to set up the flags. The only difference is that the setFlags() method removes previously added flags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664189/androidwhat-is-difference-between-setflags-and-addflags-for-intent

Comment: This answer is useless.

Comment: @DavidWasser reworked