# When do I use addFlags or setFlags for the purpose of removing activities in stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have OnBoard Activity and Login Activity. In LoginActivity after successful login I am trying to clear onboard activity using below code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

I've even tried `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` but it's also not working. So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the app starts with `OnboardActivity` and that starts `LoginActivity` and then you want to clear them both and launch `HomeActivity`?

If that is the case, I would do it this way:

- `OnboardActivity` launches `LoginActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`.
- `LoginActivity` returns a result that indicates if the login was successful or not and calls `finish()`. `LoginActivity` is no longer in the task.
- `OnboardActivity` checks the result in `OnActivityResult()` and, if the login was successful, launches `HomeActivity` (no flags needed) and calls `finish()` on itself.
- At this point, both `LoginActivity` and `OnboardActivity` are gone, and `HomeActivity` is the only `Activity` in the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with the `finishAffinity()` before moving to onboard activity. There is no need to set any flags. Because this method kills all activities in the stack and current activity as well

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use FLAGS. Even though you want to understand, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6664189/1318946)

There are two ways to finish Current Activity (LoginActivity in your case) and move to Next Activity (OnBoard in your case).:

1. Call `finish()` before starting Second Activity. It will destroy current activity.
2. Call `finishAffinity();` before starting Second Activity. It will destroy stack of all previous activity.

Hope it will helps you.