# How to load a .pdf or a .doc file in android

Tags: android

I want to show a pdf (preferably) or a word document in my app; like a privacy notice screen. Many applications have it, so it should be possible. i tried loading a simple text file as a start but doesn't provide formatting, fonts or trade mark symbols. I've gone through a few posts but I couldn't apply it to my app. Could anyone tell me how is it done? Could I store the file somewhere in res folder and provide a path to open it through my code? I looked into the following link but I'm not sure if that's the right approach in my case [android: open a pdf from my app using the built in pdf viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916108/android-open-a-pdf-from-my-app-using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer).

Comment: Why not use a HTML web page and use the WebView widget?

Comment: Was the down vote necessary? I'm quite new to android and trying to learn how it works. A simple suggestion would have been sufficient.  I'd thought about a `WebView` I also implemented it. I thought it's a little slow and user would unnecessarily have to wait a little longer for the trivial chunk of text I needed to show. Thanks anyway .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support opening PDF and DOC files natively. You'd have to make your own implementation.

Like t0mm13b said, you should consider using HTML (+ CSS) instead and use a WebView.