# How to use Droidtext inside android app to open pdf files from assests

Tags: android, pdf

I have some PDF Files in assests and i want to open the pdf files without using 3rd party apps,

I have used PDFViewer and will not render properly sometimes and also is not working on some devices.

So i found in this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027719/is-there-any-library-for-viewing-pdf-in-android-app-other-than-apv

He says "If you want to have the ability to both read and write pdf files. You can consider using DroidText Droidtext It is a port of iText java library for Android.

I have personally used it and seems good!"

So how use the jar file and implement in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the "examples" package ?

http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/source/browse/trunk/droidTextTest/src/examples/com/lowagie/examples/

For integrating that library in your project, you do it like for the others :

- Download the Jar from the project homepage.
- Create a lib folder and put the jar there.
- Right click on your project, and add your jar in the build path.

EDIT 1:
Well, you have to create a stream :

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Path/to/your/document.pdf"));
document.open();
```

EDIT 2:

I misunderstood your question : I thought you wanted to read the PDF programmatically speaking. 
DroidText is not a PDF viewer.

Comment: yes i know how to include the jar file in the class path, but how to use that jar, i mean i have a pdf file in assests how to view that using this jar?, can you please guide me

Comment: can you please explain me in detail, i hope you dont mind

Comment: i have class called reader, and have included the jar file in the lib, ok now?

Comment: yes i want to read the pdf files

Comment: @Goofy Maybe I wasn't clear : DroidText is for reading the PDF byte by byte and is used to apply edits and other "inner" file manipulations. For viewing PDFs, you can use the stock APV.

Comment: can you please help me on how to implement that

Comment: You can use intents like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10689094/644669