# Display PDF on my Android device

Tags: android

I have a couple of ebooks in PDF format, that i need to display to a application user. What are my best options ? Are there any inbuilt PDF viewers available, or will i need the user to have 3rd party applications installed ?

Kind Regards

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916108/android-open-a-pdf-from-my-app-using-the-built-in-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any inbuilt PDF viewers available

Not built into the OS. Many devices will ship with a third-party PDF viewing app that you can launch using an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with `startActivity()`.

If you want PDF rendering within your app, you will need a third-party library -- you can find options for that by searching `android pdf library` on a major search engine.